# Conditional assembly name in xmlns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In a `xaml` file, the `namespace` is as follows:

```
xmlns:vsp="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0"
```

Trouble is, for Visual Studio 2015 it will be (notice the different `assembly`)

```
xmlns:vsp="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0"
```

Is there any way of conditionally providing the xmlns or conditionally providing the `assembly` name ? Or there is another way to do this?

P.S. I rewrote this whole question as I realized my understanding of `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` was wrong. This has to go in the 'referenced' assembly's `AssemblyInfo.cs` and in the context of this question we do not have access to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` of the referenced assembly.

Comment: The following may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224538/how-to-redirect-assembly-versions-in-wpf; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions.

Comment: @ChrisMack Thanks for the idea. I do not think that will help though, if you see the assembly we have to provide in xmlns has hardcoded version in its name, so I am after something more like a conditional statement similar to #if in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could get it to work is having my own wrapper for `EnvironmentColors` (that is the only class I am using in the `xaml`).
And in the wrapper, I created properties only for the ones I am using (about 8 of them) in the lines of :

```
public static class EnvironmentColorsWrapper
{
    public static ThemeResourceKey AccentBorderBrushKey 
    { 
        get
        {
            return EnvironmentColors.AccentBorderBrushKey;
        }
    }
}
```

This `EnvironmentColorsWrapper` is used in the `xaml` file.

And `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0` & `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0` are conditionally referenced in the `csproj` file.

If someone else posts a better way to do this, I will accept it, else will accept this as the answer.